# Using Entity Framework with Telerik's Controls

Tags: c#, frameworks, telerik, entity

I have worked with products of Telerik about two week,and  in my opinion the Entity Framework is better than the Open Access(ORM), But i wonder that other Products of Telerik(EXP:GridView or ....) hasn't any problem with Entity Framework? I want to start a Project with Entity Framework and Telerik's Controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't run into any problems. Entity Framework and the Telerik Tools are compatible with one another, in fact I have used EF and Telerik together in a number of projects.

Comment: which control do you  suggestion to use with Entity Framework?

Comment: I typically use Code First Entity Framework as it produces cleaner code rather than using the EDMX file.  Not a big fan of EDMX at all.  Just keep in mind that the Telerik grids and combobox controls all require IEnumerable or IQueryable in their data source.

Answer (score 1):

We use the EntityFramework in conjunction with Telerik's controls extensively, and have not had any issues or problems.  Telerik's controls seem to always behave as expected when binding to individual objects or lists.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To take the classical 3 tier approach...

Are you asking if your data access layer (i.e. EF) is compatible with your UI (i.e. Telerik controls)?

The answer is kind of up to you as you should provide the middle layer (i.e. the business/service layer).

If you are finding direct dependencies between the two then I would advise looking at the architecture of the application.  They shouldn't be connected directly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i want to implement business layer. i dont want to connect Open Access with Telerik controlo directly